# PHP AMQPLib (RabbitMQ) Deadlocking

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

i'm using PHP AMQPLib to do some background jobs and jobs that can be done parallel. My problem is that if i have too many jobs, i'm seemingly running out of memory. So i limited the jobs to a maximum of 5 at any time. While now the maximum count of queues will stay at 6 (the main queue plus 5 callback queues), the connections still explode, which seems to lead to a deadlock.

The client will ack the incomming callback:

```
public function on_response($rep) {
    if($rep->get('correlation_id') == $this->corr_id) {
        $this->ready = true;
        $this->response = $rep->body;            

        $rep->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($rep->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
        $rep->delivery_info['channel']->queue_delete();

        $this->connection->close(); //connection is opened in constructor via  $this->connection = new AMQPConnection($host, $port, $username, $password, $vHost);
    }
}
```

while the queue is correctly closed and deleted (as said above, the maximum number of queues stays at 6 any time), the connection seems to stay open. How do i manage to actually close the now obsolete connection?

[EDIT]: The problem seems to be that i run out of ram, because RabbitMQ doesn't release the ram as long as the connection is open. so i really need to know how to properly terminate these connections...

Comment: Are you saying that connection close() doesn't close the connection? Have you tried running the library in debug mode to see the AMQP commands sent to the server? https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/blob/master/demo/config.php#L12

Comment: If you have a publishing connection, then that connection will be blocked if the memory alarm is raised

Comment: i decided that it doesn't matter really much, since the problem seems to resolve itself with a bit more ram. the ram use stabilizes at around 500MB (had tested on a VM with 256MB...)